# SQL (Oracle): group by bounded to certain columns

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

The problem is the following: I need to display the number (using `COUNT()` function) of payments made by each customer (identified with a code which is the *codcli* column) but filtered by some divisions (the *tipope* column). As you can see in the image, the number is displayed but is splitted among the divisions, while I'd like to have each customer displayed only once.

How can I filter without having the payments splitted?

[image]

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Sorry, can't see image due to corporate firewall :/ - Are you able to use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Sorry, this is the SQL query:select codcli, tipope, count(codcli) as somma_bonifici from mov
group by codcli, tipope
having tipope in ('VE5', ' VE9', 'PR5', 'PR9')
order by codcli

Comment: @AndreaZed  post desired output in tabular text format

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I didn't understand your question correctly, but why not simply:

```
SELECT CODCLI, COUNT(*) AS SOMMA_BONIFICI
FROM MOV
WHERE TIPOPE IN ( 'VE5', ' VE9', 'PR5', 'PR9')
GROUP BY CODCLI
ORDER BY CODCLI;
```

Comment: Easier! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the divisions (`Tipope`) in the outer query and have your `COUNT` in a sub query.

```
SELECT CODCLI, SUM(SELECT COUNT(sub.CODCLI) 
                   FROM mov sub
                   WHERE sub.TIPOPE = TIPOPE 
                   GROUP BY sub.CODCLI) AS SOMMA_BONIFICI
FROM mov
WHERE TIPOPE IN ('VE5', ' VE9', 'PR5', 'PR9')
GROUP BY CODCLI
ORDER BY CODCLI
```

Which would output:

```
CODCLI   SOMMA_BONIFICI
AA200078 16
AA200300 10
AA200412 3
AA200309 9
```

Comment: Already done, but I need to filter by divisions otherwise I would obtain different numbers using count() function

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @etsa me neither, i guess they didn't like my working

Comment: I'll give you my vote.   Actually your query is a bit redundant, but I don't like negative votes at all, because the don't consider the effort people do.

Comment: @etsa yeh my answer was before the extra clarification from the OP

Comment: I did. Because it will obviously give wrong results. There is no restriction on department in the subquery which means that the totals are wrong.

Comment: @fhossfel `WHERE sub.TIPOPE = TIPOPE ` links the department to the outer query which has `WHERE TIPOPE IN ('VE5', ' VE9', 'PR5', 'PR9')` so yes there is a restriction on department in the subquery.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the customer. Your query will show the number of all payments no matter of the department they have been made to. This means they will be counted more than once and the total number of payments shown will not be correct.